# Delphi 2009 interface

Tags: object-oriented, memory-management, interface, delphi

I have this code and at the end of it, FastMM shows that there were memory leaks with all the objects of `TSinc`:

```
unit sinc_int;

interface

uses
  Classes,
  log_listener_list_int,
  tick_listener_list_int;

type
  ISinc = interface;

  ISincList = interface;

  ISinc = interface ['{53814230-6308-4259-99FF-6054F2C91F9C}']
  function Execute: Boolean;
  function SincList: ISincList;
  function Log: string;
  procedure AddLog(const Texto: string);
  function LogListenerList: ILogListenerList;
  function TickListenerList: ITickListenerList;
  function SincIntervaloMili: Integer;
  function EstaSincronizando: Boolean;
  procedure Start;
  procedure Stop;
  end;

  ISincList = interface ['{F3355798-4584-4DCE-8EBA-3692B14FA132}']
  function Add(const Item: ISinc): Integer;
  function Count: Integer;
  function Get(const Index: Integer): ISinc;
  procedure Put(const Index: Integer; Item: ISinc);
  procedure Remove(const Item: ISinc);
  procedure Clear;
  procedure Start;
  procedure Stop;
  end;

implementation

end.

unit sinc_class;

interface

uses
  sinc_int, log_listener_list_int, tick_listener_list_int, sinc_thread_class;

type
  TSinc = class (TInterfacedObject, ISinc)
  protected
    FLog: string;
    FSincList: ISincList;
    FLogListenerList: ILogListenerList;
    FTickListenerList: ITickListenerList;
    FSincIntervaloMili: Integer;
    FEstaSincronizando: Boolean;
    FThread: TSincThread;
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Execute: Boolean; virtual; abstract;
    function SincList: ISincList;
    function Log: string; virtual;
    procedure AddLog(const Texto: string);
    function LogListenerList: ILogListenerList;
    function TickListenerList: ITickListenerList;
    function SincIntervaloMili: Integer;
    function EstaSincronizando: Boolean;
    procedure Start;
    procedure Stop;
  end;

implementation

uses
  sinc_list_class,
  log_listener_list_class,
  tick_listener_list_class;

{ TSinc }

procedure TSinc.AddLog(const Texto: string);
begin
  FLogListenerList.AddLog(Texto);
  FLog:=FLog+Texto;
end;

constructor TSinc.Create;
begin
  FSincList:=TSincList.Create;
  FLogListenerList:=TLogListenerList.Create;
  FTickListenerList:=TTickListenerList.Create;
  FEstaSincronizando:=False;
  FThread:=TSincThread.Create(Self);
end;

destructor TSinc.Destroy;
begin
  FSincList.Clear;
  FSincList:=nil;
  FLogListenerList.Clear;
  FLogListenerList:=nil;
  FTickListenerList.Clear;
  FTickListenerList:=nil;
  FThread.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TSinc.EstaSincronizando: Boolean;
begin
  Result:=FEstaSincronizando;
end;

function TSinc.Log: string;
begin
  Result:=FLog;
end;

function TSinc.LogListenerList: ILogListenerList;
begin
  Result:=FLogListenerList;
end;

function TSinc.SincIntervaloMili: Integer;
begin
  Result:=FSincIntervaloMili;
end;

function TSinc.SincList: ISincList;
begin
  Result:=FSincList;
end;

procedure TSinc.Start;
begin
  FEstaSincronizando:=True;
  FSincList.Start;
  FThread.Resume;
end;

procedure TSinc.Stop;
begin
  FThread.Suspend;
  FSincList.Stop;
  FEstaSincronizando:=False;
end;

function TSinc.TickListenerList: ITickListenerList;
begin
  Result:=FTickListenerList;
end;

end.
```

And when I do this:

```
procedure TForm2.btnSinc1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SincTest:=TSincTest.New;
  SincTest:=nil;
end;
```

It shows that there were memory leaks with the `TSincTest` class, its lists and even the thread.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please see [Checklist for how to write a good Code Review question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429/42632). Please also clarify if your program runs as expected, minus the memory leaks, or if the memory leaks cause fatal errors/crash of your program.

Comment: @Phrancis Thank you. I'll correct my question with the checklist and the points you made.

Comment: My guess, you declared `SincTest : TSincTest` instead of `SincTest : ISinc`, but you don't supply enough information to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to check around `TSync` as it inherits from `TInterfacedObject`, which is reference counted, a typical source of memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Unless Delphi syntax has changed since I was writing it, this code will not free the memory allocated to these object, just dereference the pointer.

```
 FSincList.Clear;
 FSincList:=nil;
 FLogListenerList.Clear;
 FLogListenerList:=nil;
 FTickListenerList.Clear;
 FTickListenerList:=nil;
```

instead of

```
  FSincList.Clear;
  FSincList:=nil;
```

just call

```
 FSincList.free;
```

This will free the memory.  You can set it to nil also if you wish.